# Specific websites throwing an exception in QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, access-violation, qwebview

While running my code I am getting a Write Access Violation Exception when it tries to use QWebView:

### Minimal compilable code for reproducing the error

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
#include <QUrl>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWebView *wv = new QWebView(this);
    wv->load(QUrl("http://steamcommunity.com/"));
    setCentralWidget(wv);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The pro file also includes `webkitwidgets` and `network`:

```
QT       += core gui webkitwidgets network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = MyApp
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

---

### Error Hints

The error I get looks like this:

```
ASSERTION FAILED: leftSide->category() != CalcOther && rightSide->category() != CalcOther
css\CSSCalculationValue.cpp(290) : WebCore::CSSCalcBinaryOperation::create
1   0354A5B7
2   02E58E41
3   02E59520
 ...
```

I can't provide a stack trace because the error is in one of the Qt files, but here is the disassembly:
[image: disassembly]

The error only occurs on specific webpages (e.g. steamcommunity.com) but not others. Is it possible that some sites just break Qt's API?

- compiler: MSVC2013 x86
- Qt version: Qt 5.5.0

Comment: It's a Qt bug. You'll have to build a debug Qt to get a sensible backtrace, and then report it.

Comment: How do I report a bug? And are they going to fix it soon or should I rather use an older version of Qt?

Comment: Paid support has its benefits :) Report bugs at https://bugreports.qt.io/ Do note that you should be using the latest 5.5.1, not 5.5.0.

Comment: Qt WebKit is a deprecated module, you should look into WebEngine instead.

Comment: @MrEricSir Thanks, I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this error is actually a Qt bug.
Its status can be viewed here: [Qt Bug Report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50681)

Using the new [Qt WebEngine Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-index.html) module worked great as a replacement for me.

Comment: It's a shame for Qt developers team, that Web Kit is so buggy even in Qt 5.5.1. They simply have neglected this renderer :(. Which version do you use for Qt Web engine? I have to support Windows XP, but Qt 5.5.1 is the last version in which Web Engine can work in Windows XP.

Comment: @ilya The Qt version I used back then was Qt 5.5.0.